# Difficulties with setting window parameters for non-Office applications

Tags: excel, vba, shell, firefox

I have an excel application (PC W10) which launches InternetExplorer with a variety of websites then sets the window size as required.  The following code works well with InternetExplorer –

```
myLink = “some website url”
Set myInt = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 'launch IE
With myInt
    .Height = hig
        'etc. for other parameters
End With
myInt.Navigate2 myLink 'go to website
Do While myInt.Busy 'wait until all is done before doing anything else
Loop
```

But now that many websites no longer support IE, I need to move to another browser (e.g. FireFox, Chrome or Edge) –

```
myLink = “some website url”
myInt = “FireFox”
appName = “firefox.exe"
appPath = "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\"
myApp = Shell(appPath & appName & " -url " & myLink)
    'Up to here all is well
    'The intended code below obviously does not work
With myInt
    .Height = hig
        'etc. for other parameters
End With
Do While myInt.Busy
Loop
```

The above launches the browser and website OK, but I cannot find how to control the window’s dimensions and create a wait loop.

I would greatly appreciate any direction anyone could give me.

Best regards
greenme

Comment: From VBA you can only work directly with the IE because that is the only browser with an integrated Microsoft COM interface https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model To use other browsers with VBA you must use Selenium https://www.selenium.dev/

Comment: Thank you Zwenn, I thought this might be the answer.  I will have a go at it.
Your advice is much appreciated.